# Trying to test a new version of a Spotify app without the live version affecting it

Tags: spotify

We currently have an app live on the Spotify app platform. But when we try to test a new version, locally, the live version seems to conflict with it. We are unable to view the local version which is preventing us from being able to test before updating.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Have you tried emailing the Spotify team?  They may be able to give you inside tips as to how to fix this.  On another note, what is this app that you are developing?  I am a huge spotify user, and like to find new useful (or cool) apps to use.

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah I have spoken to them. I think it’s more to do with a legacy version on my machine. Not easy to clear Spotify cache. You can find the app here (it's a fundraising app) but it’s UK only: open.spotify.com/app/guilty-pledgers

Comment: Even though I am not in the UK (I am in the US), I was able to open it, and it looks great!  If I had a facebook account, I have a feeling I may favorite that and possibly use it!  Good work!

Comment: Thanks! :) nice to hear